# Scroll to item not working properly in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I have a banner and below banner I have a header which I am fixing when I reach the header like this

```
const nav = document.querySelector("#header");
const topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;

function fixNav() {
  if (window.scrollY >= topOfNav) {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + "px";
    document.body.classList.add("nav-is-stuck");
  } else {
    document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    document.body.classList.remove("nav-is-stuck");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", fixNav);
```

Now my other requirement is that when I click on menu item I want to reach the top of the section. For that I have written this code

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches(".navigation__list--link")) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  const id = event.target.getAttribute("href").replace("#", "");
  const element = document.getElementById(id);

  console.log(element);

  element.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
});
```

The issue that when I click on the menu item it doesn't go the start of the section but some of my section goes behind the header.

Also when I click on the last section it doesn't go the start of that section, maybe because I don't have enough space (height) on the last section?

Not looking for jQuery solutions

Comment: create a div  right after the Header Menu and then make "Id" and style should be display="None".    <div id="TopHeaderId" style="display:none;"> and now use the "TopHeaderId" to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: - Do step 1 right after the Header Menu

```
<div id="topid" style="display:none"> </div>
```

Step 2:
Now just call hidden div id from button or from any where you want.
like this

```
<a href="#topid">GO TO Top </a>
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks for guiding.